# Google chart breaks into two

Tags: charts, google-visualization, linechart

I have given the data in the correct order. The render is somehow split between
2019 and 2018 and that too 2019 first and then 2018. Is there a fix for this? Or some property that causes this to happen?[image]

The code is as follows:

```
import {GoogleCharts} from 'google-charts';
    let graphRows = []
    graphs[index].forEach(element => {
        let dataArray = [];
        dataArray.push(new Date(element["Date"].toString()));
        dataArray.push(element['Net Asset Value']);
        graphRows.push(dataArray);
    });

    //Load the charts library with a callback
    GoogleCharts.load(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        // Standard google charts functionality is available as GoogleCharts.api after load
        const data = new GoogleCharts.api.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('date', 'Time');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Net Asset Value');


        data.addRows(graphRows);
        // data.addRows(graphRowsReversed);

        var options = {
            hAxis: {
                title: 'Date'
            },
            vAxis: {
                title: 'Value'
            },
            explorer: { axis: 'horizontal' }
        };
        const line_chart = new GoogleCharts.api.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart-div'));
        line_chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

`graphs[index]` is an array of objects each of which looks like this:

```
{
    "Scheme Code": 145633,
    "Scheme Name": "Mirae Asset Nifty 50 ETF (MAN50ETF)",
    "ISIN Div Payout": {
     "ISIN Growth": "INF769K01EG9"
    },
    "ISIN Div Reinvestment": "",
    "Net Asset Value": 116.917,
    "Repurchase Price": null,
    "Sale Price": null,
    "Date": "09-Apr-2019"
}
```

Comment: The data is an array of arrays, each of the arrays of value something like this [-002019-02-05T18:06:32.000Z, 10.1], that is, date and value.

Comment: in order to provide assistance, it would be helpful to see the code used to draw the chart, and a sample of the data...